# New XFX Radeon 6600 xt crashes in every game

Tags: graphics-card, crash, amd-radeon

I have bought few days ago xfx radeon rx 6600 xt but every time I want to play any game it just crashes after few seconds. I used to have nvidia card so I removed all their drivers but no luck.

Other specs: CPU - i7 4790K PSU - 750W Memory - 8 GB

If someone has other solutions rather then updating RAM from 8 to 16 GB I would like to know. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have the proper drivers installed

Comment: Install the driver from the [website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6600-series/amd-radeon-rx-6600). What is your Windows version?

Comment: I have latest drivers installed and windows 10 pro 64 bit.

Comment: Having the same exact problem with the same exact card.